# jquery get closest hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select the div with id = B when selecting any checkboxes

```
<div id="a"><div style="display:none;" id="B"></div></div>
<ul>
<li><input type='checkbox'></li>
<li><input type='checkbox'></li>
<li><input type='checkbox'></li>
</ul>
```

The following returns undefined;

```
$(this).closest("div:hidden").attr("id")
```

Any help?

Comment: try dirty: `$(this).closest("div[style='display:none;']").attr("id")`

Comment: `$(this)` what is this here?

Comment: The `div` with an id of `b` is a child node of this div. You may have to reach it like this. `$(this).closest('div').find('div:hidden').attr('id')`

Comment: @PalashMondal Cause then you could simple write: `"B";` I would think that the ID is unknown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) travel up the dom tree what you want; is to get the ul element and then get the `div:hidden` [sibling](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(this).closest("ul").siblings("div:hidden").attr("id");
```

This is based on that `this` refers to a child, grandchild, great grandchild, N-child of the ul element.

---

As T.J. Crowder points out this will only work if the div is a sibling of the ul and not a child node of a sibling: This snippet looks for child nodes of siblings:

```
$(this).closest("ul").siblings().find("div:hidden").attr("id");
```

Comment: Close, but not quite, it's not a sibling of the `ul`. You'd need `$(this).closest("ul").siblings().children("div:hidden").attr("id");` which doesn't sound like a good idea, the structure probably needs changing.

Comment: It's a child node of the div where `id="a"` above the `ul`

Comment: Thanks it works. now one more question, how can I select the same div when its not hidden!

Comment: @ComeRun Add a class to your div then you don't have to update the jQuery based on whether it's hidden or not

Comment: @ComeRun: The problem with this is that if there are other siblings with hidden children, you'll get the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$('ul').change(function(){
   $('#B').show();
});
```

I should prefer to put an id on the UL tag tho and refer to that ID

```
<div id="a">
    <div style="display:none;" id="B"></div>
</div>
<ul id="theUl">
    <li><input type='checkbox' /></li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' /></li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' /></li>
</ul>


 $('#theUl').change(function(){
       $('#B').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is go up to the `ul`, back to the previous `div`, and then down to its hidden child. So:

```
var id = $(this).closest('ul').prev().children('div:hidden').attr(id);
```